# Call function pointer in an object inside a Vector

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector

I am trying to implement Observers and a Subject design pattern...

I have a object Subject, with a vector of pointers to Observers. Each Observer has a pointer to a function. How do I call it?

In this class, it's defined the function that I want to call

```
class functions_class
{
  static bool getVal(){
     return true;
  }
};
```

In this class, the vector containing the observer is defined

```
class Subject
{
      vector<Observer*> mViews;

   public:
      void addObserver(Observer *o)
      {
         mViews.push_back(o)
      }
};
```

In this class, the function pointer is stored. There is a function to call this pointer

```
class Observer
{
   typedef bool(*boolPtr)(void);
   boolPtr mPtr;

   Observer(boolPtr ptr)
   {
      mPtr = ptr;
   }

   bool call()
   {
      return (mPtr)();
   }
};
```

This is where objects are created

```
    Subject s;
    Observer o(functions_class::getVal);
    s.addObserver(&o);
```

QUESTION.........
How do I call the function pointer in observer??
I'm using a generic function in observer, but I can't make it work.

I tried:

```
(s.mViews[0].call)()
```

Any idea?

Is it also possible to cast the output of the function call to an uint32_t?

Comment: Try `s.mViews[0]->call();`

Answer (score 5):

What is `s.m_views[0]`? Well, according to the shown code, the `m_views` class member is a

```
vector<Observer*> mViews;
```

Therefore, `s.m_views[0]` gets you an `Observer *`.

So, it logically follows, that given that this is a pointer, then:

```
s.m_views[0]->call()
```

This invokes the member function.